# How to pass value from jQuery script into ActionLink in MVC razor view

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

Hi all quick question i hope.

I want to pass a value from a jQuery script into HTML.ActionLink to details action in controller

It working like i choose item in dropdownlist and in jQuery i get an id of that item after it i want to get that id be passed into ActionLink how can i achieve it or what i supose to change in my code.

```
<script>
$(function() {
       $('#reductions').change(function () {
           var Id = $('#reductions').val();
           });
       });
</script>

        <div class="form-horizontal">
            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="col-md-10">
 @Html.DropDownList("reductions", new SelectList(dbContext.Reductions,"ReductionId", "Name")  
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
@Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", "Reductions", new {id = ????WHAT PUT HERE?????}, new {})
```

Please tell me what should i change in script area or in Action Link that i could make i work.
I already study a lot of examples but no one seems to be working for me

Comment: Post the rendered action link html please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using the ActionLink Method create a normal HTML link and overwrite the href attribute with jquery.

```
<script>
   $(function() {
    var link = '@Url.Action("Details", "Details", "Reductions", new { id = "_myid_" })';
    $('#reductions').change(function () {
       var id = $('#reductions').val();
       $('#myLink').attr('href', link.replace('_myid_', id);
       });
   });
</script>

... Your other html

<a id="myLink" href="">Details</a>
```

Comment: i followed Your answer, seems best for me as i already using jQuery for other purposes and using KyleT answer interrupt with calling controller action after button click.

Thank for help.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using plain HTML forms use this:

```
@using(HTML.BeginForm("Details","Reductions"))
{
  //Your current HTML
}
```

You should also be using the @HTML.DropDownListFor() helper like this:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor("reductions", new SelectList(DBContext.Reductions, "ReductionId", "Name"), new { @class = "anyCSSClass" })
```

Replace your current @HTML.DropDownList() helper with this one.

To finish you must submit the form data to the server like this:

```
button type="submit" class="CSSClass" id="generatedContent"> Generate </button>
```

Heres the final code:

```
@using(HTML.BeginForm("Details","Reductions"))
{
  @Html.DropDownListFor("reductions", new SelectList(DBContext.Reductions,  "ReductionId", "Name"), new { @class = "anyCSSClass" })

  button type="submit" class="CSSClass" id="generatedContent"> Generate </button>
}
```

You can accomplish this using JQuery/AJAX but its a lot more hassle than its worth as it goes against fundamental concepts of MVC and keeping server side logic separate from client side logic.

P.S. Check out the overloaded methods for both helpers [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.html.linkextensions_methods%28v=vs.118%29.aspx) in the event that I mixed up the names of your controller/action methods.